# strtotime returns 1970 when I remove a month?

Tags: php, strtotime

According to the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php), I'm using strtotime correctly, but apparently I've managed to get something wrong.

The following code:

```
echo date("Y,n,j", strtotime($event["StartDate"]));
```

Outputs: `2013,4,18` (which is correct)

Whereas the following code (using the exact same data):

```
echo date("Y,n,j", strtotime('-1 month', $event["StartDate"]));
```

Outputs: `1969,12,1` (instead of `2013,3,18`)

Why?

Comment: Do you need to wrap `$event['StartDate']` in another strtotime call?

Comment: On a side note _To avoid potential ambiguity, it's best to use ISO 8601 (YYYY-MM-DD)_ [source](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php#refsect1-function.strtotime-notes)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`echo date("Y,n,j", strtotime('-1 month', strtotime($event["StartDate"])));`